# Geometric inequality with variable point in a triangle and circumcircles' radii

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

### Problem statement

> Let $\triangle ABC$ a triangle and $M$ a point inside it. Let $\mathcal{C_c}$ be the circumcircle of $\triangle MAB$ and $\mathcal{C_a}$ and $\mathcal{C_b}$ similarly defined. Note $R_a$, $R_b$ and $R_c$ the radii of these circles. Prove that:
> $$R_a + R_b + R_c \geq MA + MB + MC$$

### Figure (made using GeoGebra Geometry)

[image: GeoGebra Geometry Figure]

### Attempt (basic observations)

Firstly, I denoted the circumcenters $O_a$, $O_b$ and $O_c$, as in the figure. The statement rewrites:
$$MO_a + MO_b + MO_c \geq MA + MB + MC$$

Secondly, I have tried to find the solution for the equality case. I observed that, if $M := O$, $MA = MB = MC$, but still nothing to relate with $MO_a$, $MO_b$, $MO_c$. But I think this may be the point I'm looking for.

### Background and geometric tools that I am able to use

Synthetic geometry (Euclidean), I am also able to use vectors and analytic geometry (only Cartesian formulae).

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h364437 obtained using the very efficient formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: @JeanMarie, thanks for sharing